# Uploading m/analysing raster vector data in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster, raster2pgsql

I am trying to build a web-GIS platform where user can upload their data (raster & vector) and do some kind of analysis, like calculate zonal statistics. I read lots of articles and blogs about storing raster in PostGIS. I tried to upload raster using `raster2pgsql` command line. For the 10 MB raster, it takes 30+ second to upload in Postgres. I don't think it is the problem of my PC. In case for large raster (around 1 GB), It will take more than 5 min. I think it is not a good case what user wants.

For uploading the raster, I found lots of methods, like some developer prefer to upload as a tile (100*100), some of them upload without tile, some makes pyramids.

Can anyone suggest a way to upload the raster?

Some of the developers also prefer to store `raster` outside the database. But it will be slower.

Also If I tried to run some of the rasters analysis, It takes lots of time to get the output.

For example, I tried to calculate the zonal statists based on the district name with `agri` as the name of the raster. But it takes around 1 minute to run. In the case of web-platform, I know user can't stay waiting for a long time.

```
SELECT
    (ST_SummaryStats(ST_Clip(agri.rast, district.geom, TRUE))).*,
    district.name AS districtName
    district.geom AS geom
FROM agri, district;
```

How can I speed up the upload and analysis of raster with this method to achieve speed like in ArcGIS and QGIS?